# typescript Map get or default

Tags: javascript, typescript

kinda new to JS/TS, I am trying to implement something like Java Map getOrDefault() method which if an object is not found in a Map, return a default value. I have tried the following code which I think it should work but somehow the return type still contains undefined as `Set<number>|undefined`

Here is my sample code:

```
 const resultMap = new Map<number, Set<number>>();
 const index = 0;
 const a = resultMap.get(index) ?? resultMap.set(index, new Set<number>()).get(index);
```

TS complier is complaining the variable `a` is still `Set<number>|undefined`  which I am expecting it should be `Set<number>` as if there was a Set previously put into the map for the index, it should return left hand expression and if it's undefined, then the right hand expression will put a new Set, then returns it. I think I am missing some simple things here.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Typescript only knows what `get()` returns. Add a `!` suffix to tell it you know better... `.get(index)!`

Comment: `let a = resultMap.get(index); if (!a) { a = new Set<number>(); resultMap.set(index, a); }`